# Spinnaker Deploying the last build from Jenkins

Tags: spinnaker

I am using Spinnaker with Jenkins. When creating a server group we have to specify the image which needs to be deployed. But my jenkins job creates an image which I want to deploy using Spinnaker. My jenkins Job number is the tag. but I am not able to find a way to mention the tag dynamically. I am able to figure out that the build number is available in parameter "context.buildInfo.number" but to use this as tag number is something which I am not able to figure out.

Thanks in advance

Amol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for an update I was able to resolve the problem by creating a trigger for DockerRegistry. Now one of my Pipeline Starts the Job and pushes the build to DockerRegistry. And another pipeline to monitor the images from there. It can pickup the latest build from the registry and deploy that.